# How can I use a monospace font with PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I am trying to use the "Courier" font with PDFsharp to use its monospace feature, but when I use this font using the library the written text is not monospaced or fixed-width.

This is the code:

```
// Obtain an XGraphics object to render to
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

// Create a font
double fontHeight = 8;
XFont font = new XFont("Courier", fontHeight, XFontStyle.Regular);
XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);

String text = "Hello\r\nMy name is John\r\nMy name, is Peter.";
XRect rect = new XRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.SeaShell, rect);
tf.DrawString(text, font, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

The letter "i" and the character "." break the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a font that is installed on your computer, for example "Courier New" instead of "Courier".

Comment: I have just solved the issue with that change, but you was fastest. Thank you. I saw in MSWord that there isn't "Courier" font.